# Is there any method to store the image in a flet canvas control

Tags: flet

I would like to use the Flutter Canvas Control as described in the tutorial and save the hand-drawn image as a PNG or TIFF file.
The Canvas Control lacks a method for this. So, how can the image be saved?

import flet as ft
import flet.canvas as cv
import io
from PIL import Image

class State:
x: float
y: float

state = State()

def main(page: ft.Page):
page.title = "Brush"

```
def pan_start(e: ft.DragStartEvent):
    state.x = e.local_x
    state.y = e.local_y

def pan_update(e: ft.DragUpdateEvent):
    cp.shapes.append(
        cv.Line(
            state.x, state.y, e.local_x, e.local_y, paint=ft.Paint(stroke_width=3)
        )
    )
    cp.update()
    state.x = e.local_x
    state.y = e.local_y

def save_as_tiff():
    # Speichern der Canvas-Zeichnung als TIFF-Datei
    img_data = cp.to_image()  # Wandelt die Canvas in Bilddaten um
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))
    image.save("zeichnung.tiff", format="TIFF")

cp = cv.Canvas(
    [
        cv.Fill(
            ft.Paint(
                gradient=ft.PaintLinearGradient(
                    (0, 0), (600, 600), colors=[ft.colors.CYAN_50, ft.colors.GREY]
                )
            )
        ),
    ],
    content=ft.GestureDetector(
        on_pan_start=pan_start,
        on_pan_update=pan_update,
        drag_interval=10,
    ),
    expand=False,
)

save_button = ft.ElevatedButton("Speichern als TIFF", on_click=lambda e: save_as_tiff())

page.add(
    ft.Container(
        cp,
        border_radius=5,
        width=float("inf"),
        expand=True,
    ),
    save_button
)
```

ft.app(main)

I got fallowing error:
AttributeError: 'Canvas' object has no attribute 'to_image'